# Brep Ruled (Creating brep from 2 surfaces) not creating properly

Tags: c#, eyeshot

// Sorting the surfaces by their y positions

```
var ySurfaces = brep.ConvertToSurfaces().ToList();
ySurfaces.Sort((surface1, surface2) =>
{
                surface1.Regen(1);
                surface2.Regen(1);
                return surface1.BoxMax.Y.CompareTo(surface2.BoxMax.Y);
});
```

// getting the end surfaces

```
var bottom = ySurfaces.First();
var top = ySurfaces.Last();
// below is the image for the end surfaces both are similar
[end surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoyrh.png)
// creating the brep from the surfaces
```

```
var createdSolid = Ruled(bottom, top);
```

// below is the image for createdSolid
[createdSolid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpeMu.png)

```
top.Rotate(Math.PI, Vector3D.AxisX);

var newSolid = Ruled(bottom, top);
```

// below is the image for the newSolid
[newSolid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFMMP.png)

this is my opinion

I think the order of the curves might be different but i don't know how to correct the order.
i need some help
and i am using eyeshot 2023 version

I want to create the solid or brep with the 2 surfaces but the result i am getting is not joined properly